# Is read only access available for cases

Tags: civicase

My client needs some users to have read only acccess to contacts, but for activities and cases this doesn't look to be possible. There seems to be nothing to provide view access only for cases.  I know there is an extension for activity access, but is there something for cases too?    This is Drupal 7 based.